Embedding of $L_p$ distance
I try to see if there is a way to visualize 2D $L_p$ norm/metric. For $p=2$ it's easy, this is the usual flat cartesian plane, but for other values of $p$ is there a way to plot a kind of grid (which could curved and be embedded in 3D space) which respects $L_p$ distance, namely, for every points $P=(x;y)$ in this space, the distance between this point and the origin should be
$d_p(x;y) = \sqrt[p]{|x|^p + |y|^p}$
One approach I tried is to look for a function $z(x;y)$ such that the arc length formula applied to this function would give the $L_p$ distance formula ; I wrote something like (integrating over a path parametrized by $t$)
$\displaystyle\int_0^1 \sqrt{x'^2(t) + y'^2(t) + z'^2(t)}dt = \sqrt[p]{|x|^p + |y|^p}$
but it feels like it's complete non-sense ^^'
On the contrary, are there theorems that states that such an emmbedding (even in 4D or higher) is impossible ?
Any help/idea/knowledge ?

For any metric you can always look at the unit circle to get some geometric intuition. For the $L_p$ norm/metric it will be a superellipse. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse

@CyclotomicField I know how the unit circle get deformed, but I would like to see how the grid deformes ^^ But thanks !
